# Small updates not applying with WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have WiX building MSIs as part of my automated build. I want the user to be able to install one of these builds and then be able to install the next day's version on top of it.

Doing a minor or major upgrade which would require changing the build number within the [`ProductVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), I don't see to be an option for several reasons:

Firstly that the only thing I could think to peg it to is either the subversion revision or the build number but that number overflows at 65,535 which we could hit in the future. Secondly that number is already in use for distributing bug fix releases to customers.

So if I cannot change the `ProductVersion` then the only option left to me is a [Small Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579%28v=vs.120%29.aspx). I tried to achieve this by making sure the package code in the [revision number summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371255%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) had changed by not specifying an `id` for the `package` element which according to the [documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html) will result in a new one being generated each time.

`<Package InstallerVersion="405" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />`

However when running the MSI this generates an error dialog appears warning the user that this product is already installed. The only way to install it is to pass [additional command line arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367575%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) to `msiexec` and even that doesn't seem to actually reinstall the components.

Changing the `ProductCode` to be automatically generated `<Product Id="*"...>` but not changing the `ProductVersion` seems to follows the rules described for [setting `AllowSameVersionUpgrades`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html) to `no` which is the default value. This means Windows Installer treats it as a separate package and installs it alongside the first one but again does not seem to overwrite the installed files, just adds an entry in the installed programs table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a small update or minor upgrade includes the fact that you need to specify REINSTALL and REINSTALLMODE - that's just the definition of how to apply them because as you say, that product code is already installed and you can't reinstall it, only update it with a command line update.

You could package the MSI inside a zipped up exe that extracts the MSI and runs it with the appropriate command line, you may need to write a small program to run the MSI depending on whether the self extracting exe tool lets you run external commands. The only other thing I can think of is that you use one of the ooher fields of ProductVersion to indicate that this is NOT a customer product, (such as minor=254) and that leaves you free to use build number up to 65535, at which point do a major upgrade. In practice that may be a long time.

Changing the ProductCode just makes it a new product and yes therefore it will install side by side unless you have specified a major upgrade.